# Overriding a click within a contentEditable div such that cursor position doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the user to be able to click on a  within a  that has contentEditable="true", and have my code take an action based on this click, but *not* have the cursor repositioned to within the span.

Is this possible?  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need the cursor to be put back where it was, or just there be no selection at all?